# Check for Updates functionality For Windows application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, installation, installshield

I am using Install shield limited edition to install my WPF application.

My current scenario is like this.

- The created set up is available in our website  for downloading.
- User can download and then Install the set up on their own machines.
- I have option to modify  the software and will update the modified
  installer into the website , so that users will get the    updated
  software.

My Next step:

In my application I am going to include “Maintenance release (Download Updates)” functionality. So that users can download the latest updations automatically from the software itself.

How Can I do this.? Any help would be appreciated. 
Is there any facility in the Install shield for this?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [NAppUpdate](https://github.com/synhershko/NAppUpdate). It provides a framework with features for all tasks required for an update process. For example, it lets you check for updates from various sources (Web http / ftp), trigger update checks and replace your binaries with the updated ones.

You still will have to integrate this into your app, so it is not an "out of the box" solution. But my experience is that most out-of-the-box solutions eventually cause headaches due to limited customization possibilities and moreover are rarely free (if this is important to you).

A good introductory article can be found here: [The philosophy behind NAppUpdate](http://code972.com/blog/2012/06/55-the-philosophy-behind-nappupdate).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any facility to add that feature through install shield but there is a software update framework for .NET called **NetSparkle**. You can try that if you want. If you want to implement something on your own then its better to some other websites like code project that provide startup code or similar projects.

Here 's the link for [NetSparkle](https://netsparkle.codeplex.com/).

There is also a similar question on StackOverflow : [Code to check for updates, install new version of app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907425/code-to-check-for-updates-install-new-version-of-app)